# OracleCommand cannot convert 0 to boolean

Tags: c#, oracle11g

I'm getting a Specified cast is not valid. When I execute the follow code:

---

incident.InjuryPM = Convert.IsDBNull(reader["CAD_INJ_TIME_PM"]) ? false : Convert.ToBoolean(reader["CAD_INJ_TIME_PM"]);

---

- incident.InjuryPM property is of Type boolean.
- The type of CAD_INJ_TIME_PM is VARCHAR2(2 byte).
- The value of CAD_INJ_TIME_PM is "0".
- The reader is of type OracleDataReader

I am pretty new to Oracle 11g so perhaps I'm missing something. Thanks

Comment: actually there is a lot of source than using the RAW ado.net plumbing is dangerous. Consider using some micro-orm to remove that, because tomoroow you'll face another issue, and another again and so on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C# Convert.ToBoolean() does not accept the strings "0" or "1", only variants of "true" or "false". Thus, if you have a varchar(2) string as your column type, you'll likely need to convert to int first:

```
Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32(reader["CAD_INJ_TIME_PM"]))
```

Comment: I did try to do reader["CAD_INJ_TIME_PM"] as int? 
it returned Null

Comment: @Jesse, using `as int` isn't going to work. The `Int32` class is a value type.

Comment: @Jesse furthermore, since the actual type of the column is a string, you need Convert or int.Parse to get it to an integer value. You can't simply cast it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you're looking for this:

```
reader.IsDbNull(idx) ? false : Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32(reader[idx]));
```

where `idx` is the index of the field you're after.

Comment: The Reader I'm using is a OracleDataReader. I'm not seeing a GetBoolean method.

Comment: @Jesse, and based on the update in your question about the underlying value of the data field, you need to convert it to an `Int32` first as well.